Which way to correct for autocorrelation in GAM in timeseries (corARMA/corAR1/corCAR1)?
I was wondering if there are any noteworthy differences in how to correct for $\text{AR}=1$ in a GAM, where time is continuous considering the three different methods here (the data has been collected every month for each subject). Would the right method be corCAR1?

Method 1: Incl. correlation = corARMA(form = ~ Timepoint|subject, p=1))

Method 2: Incl. correlation = corAR1(form = ~ Timepoint|subject ))

Method 3: Incl. correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ Timepoint|subject ))



What do you mean by $\text{AR} = 1$? Are you implying that you believe the observations are contaminated with autoregressive noise and wish to model this with an AR(1) process?
If so, then I believe all three correlation functions will do what you want if your data is collected as you suggest, regularly by month (with perhaps some months missing).
While time is continuous, if your data are regularly spaced in time, then we'd consider this discrete time. If this is how your data are collected then corAR1() would be the function of choice to model this dependence as there is a particular algorithm that allows for the AR(1) to be fitted  relatively efficiently. The corARMA(p = 1) will estimate the same model, but because this is a more general function it will take longer to compute the same model. Likewise for corCAR1().
If your observations are not regularly spaced in time — for example while they were collected roughly monthly, they were collected on different days within each month and hence a varying number of days separates each observation — then you should use corCAR1() which would allow observations separate by amount of time $\Delta t$ to be correlated as $\phi^{\Delta t}$, where $\phi$ is the estimated autocorrelation parameter. This contrasts with the AR(1), where observations one time unit apart are correlated $\rho^1 = \rho$, two units apart $\rho^2$, up to $\rho^{n-1}$, where $n$ is the number of observations in the series.
If you are willing to guesstimate or state a value for $\rho$ and your observations are regularly spaced in time, you could use bam(..., rho = guess, AR.start = I), where guess is your estimate or chosen value of $\rho$ and I is something that codes for the start points of each series (see ?bam for details). If your data are regularly spaced, bam() would be especially preferable to fitting with gamm() if you are fitting a model with a non-Gaussian family.

Here the specifications are similar but have some distinct differences:

The corAR1 autocorrelation function only has the capability of estimating autocorrelation in a regression (rather than other aspects of time series analysis).
The corARMA function allows more flexibility because it can also include moving averages (the "MA" part). The corAR1 function is a sort of special case of corARMA, in that it only includes the AR part. Sometimes you can only use the corARMA version based off the model you are fitting.
The corCAR1 function estimates autocorrelation in a vein similar to corAR1, however it allows one to specify autocorrelation for models which contain unevenly spaced units of time.

I'm guessing for your purposes, any of these would work if you were only interested in a first-order autocorrelation structure, with the caveat that the third class has more flexibility with uneven time units.

The description of the corCAR1() process is wrong. It is a generalisation of the AR(1) to the setting where the data are no-longer evenly spaced in time. It has nothing to do with time varying coefficients; the form argument in all these correlation functions is there simply to describe how the data are arranged in time. Are the data one long series or are there multiple series, a single series per level of the grouping factor

I see that I was misinformed on that point. I have edited the answer in hopes that it is more accurate now.
